# Animate html tag by changing position isn't smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I would animate one image along an ellipse path.
I have a problem with this function that i repeat each 60 times at second.

```
function updateTick(){
    actualDegree += incrementDegree;
    for(var i = 0; i < ads.length; i++){
        sin = Math.sin(actualDegree + (Math.PI * 2 / len * (i + 1) ));
        cos = Math.cos(actualDegree + (Math.PI * 2 / len * (i + 1) ));

        var zIndex = ( cos + 1 ) / (2);
        zIndex = parseInt(zIndex * len);

        adsBox[i].css({
            marginLeft: adsBox[i].data("mLeft") + ( radX * sin ),
            marginTop: adsBox[i].data("mTop") + ( radY * cos ),
            zIndex: zIndex
        });
    }
}
timerID = setInterval(updateTick, interval);
```

The problem is that the animations of these objects aren't smooth.

This [Laggy animation](http://jsfiddle.net/62y2wn61/9/) is an example of what I do and as you can see this isn't like the css3 animation [Smooth animation](http://jsfiddle.net/r4AFV/)

Comment: Here's a version optimized by replacing `top:x;left:y;` with `transform: translate(x,y);` and calling the update using `requestAnimationFrame`: http://jsfiddle.net/62y2wn61/11/

Comment: Ok thanks, this works, but I have another problem, the bug now is on the  children, that is an example, if I put text or images into the animated element the children can't move smooth.
This is the example : http://jsfiddle.net/62y2wn61/13/